# Rename [compiler] to [compiler-construction]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Currently the tags [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) and [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction) are synonyms with [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) being the main one. The tag wiki (as well as the excerpt) makes clear how the tag is supposed to be used:

> The tag [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

However no one reads the tag wiki (or the excerpt). As a result I (and presumably other people as well) remove the [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) tag from questions asking about compilation errors, how to install a given compiler, how to use a given compiler or even why a given piece of code acts the way it does multiple times a day.

One might say that the problem here is that no one reads the tag description, but that's not a problem that can be easily fixed, so let's address one that can: The name of the tag is too vague. If the tag were called [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction), that would hopefully fix the problem.

One way to achieve this would be to simply change the direction of the synonym (i.e. make [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction) the main tag), but that might not be enough. People might still just tag the question [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) without noticing that it's a synonym (if they don't read the excerpt when adding a tag they might not read the tag name either).

So my proposed solution is to remove the tag synonym and retag all existing [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler) questions to [compiler-construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-construction) (under the assumption that most questions where the tag has not been removed yet are in fact correctly tagged).

Comment: Tag blacklisting essentially does not exist.  It's reserved for only the most egregious of tags, and is only available to SE corporate, not to moderators.  There are currently about a dozen such tags in the list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair enough. I'll cut that part then.

Comment: This explains the sudden influx of ['compiler-construction'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4346/compiler-construction) badges given out yesterday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completed.

Note that there are still questions that have this tag that shouldn't, mostly because someone typed `[[language]] [compiler]` into the tag box.

Comment: Why do I still get redirected to [compiler] when I search for [compiler-construction]? Is this a cache issue that's going to fix itself?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm giving it some time.  Adding a Tag Wiki to [compiler-construction] would probably help.

Comment: [compiler-construction] has a [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler-construction/info) (the one previously used by [compiler]). It can be reached by clicking the "about" link next to the [compiler] tag on the right of the [compiler] tag page (though the top bar does not show that there's a tag wiki). The right bar of the tag wiki says that compiler is a synonym for compiler-construction, but if I click on it to get to the synonyms page, I get a 404.

Comment: Merges are always a bit perilous.  I'll look into it.

Comment: [compiler] now seems to be a synonym for [compiler-construction] - is that intended, or just a hopefully temporary glitch?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: It's intended.  If you can think of a legitimate and useful need for the tag [compiler] that doesn't involve designing or writing one, I'm all ears.

Comment: I can't, but I'd rather people weren't tempted to use it by having it seem to exist already. And if they did use it then it could be re-deleted pretty quickly if it was properly isolated from compiler-construction.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: Having it as a synonym forces the tag to [compiler-construction] when they attempt to use it, a clearly visual indication that they're using the tag incorrectly, especially if they're simply typing a sentence into the tags box.

Comment: That's not the behaviour I see when I start composing a question - I can type "compiler" into the tags box and it stays that way even when I tab awy from that box.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: When you post the question, the tag will get renamed.

Comment: Right, but that seems a bit late to discourage people. Anyway, if that's the standard approach I can live with it, but I don't think it's actually going to help that much. I've certainly cleaned out a couple of uses since the change, but it's hard to say what the overall rate is.

Comment: I agree with Ganesh that the synonym should be removed. The tag keeps being misused. I've seen some cases where the tag was removed by the OP shortly after asking the question, but there's also plenty of cases where the tag is simply kept until I or someone else remove it.